# Layout of Text in Components

Tags: codenameone

I have a couple of questions on text layout in Codenameone I can't seem to find answers to in the docs, videos or forums.

1. Is it possible to break, wrap text into multiple lines based on the text, such as a newline "\n", or can this only be done by creating a label for each line.
2. Also is it possible to rotate buttons / labels by 90 degrees, so that text is rotated, I see graphics can be rotated but not sure about how to do for components or text within them.

Any hints of tips would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Spanlabel for multiline label
2. Use the following code to rotate a button

   ```
   public class RotatedButton extends Button {

      @Override
      public void paint(Graphics g) {
          g.rotate((float)(Math.PI/4.0), getAbsoluteX(), getAbsoluteY());
          super.paint(g);
          g.resetAffine();
      }
   }
   RotatedButton btn = new RotatedButton();
   btn.setText("Hi");
   ```

Comment: Edited to use a button and remove the gradient usage which should be avoided